# Linking doesn't work properly...

Tags: bug, linked-questions

I linked [this question (q1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115230/19341) in the body of this  [question (q2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/283142/19341) but it doesn't show up in the "Linked questions" area:

[image]

The only one that shows up there is a link from [this question (q3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101471/19341) to (q2) and this link is also present in (q3):
[image]

Comment: Interesting. [This is how linking is supposed to work](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/), which is a bit different from what you saw.

Comment: @WillieWong it's getting stranger...

Comment: I have experienced some delay on some occasions, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6526/why-do-linked-questions-added-in-comments-appear-in-the-list-with-delay).

Comment: @MartinSleziak *asked 11 hours ago*...ok let's give the system some time. We are all just human beings, [aren't we](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/captcha)?

Comment: @draks I've noticed you've edited some tag-wikis and tag-excerpts. Markdown does not work in tag-excerpts - just have a look on the top of [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/badges) or hover with your mouse above a tag. I think that in most cases it's better to give links only in tag-wikis, tag-excerpts are more suitable for short characterization of the tag.

Comment: @MartinSleziak ok thanks for the hint. Cheers,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok now it's there:

[image]

Comment: I put an advice in the corresponding [tag wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/linked-questions/info)...