# Linking doesn't work properly again...

Tags: bug, linked-questions

There are two outgoing links in this question of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477652/19341), but only an incoming link is shown in the "Linked" box.

What wrong here? Seems like this question of mine: [Summing over...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115230/19341) is involved in at least two  linking  issues, since ít was already involved [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8260/19341)...

**EDIT**

Also an incoming link from this question [Number of ways, powers of $2$ sum up specific values](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/603527/19341) doesn't appear in the "Linked" section of this question [What's the non-trivial root of $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n x^{2^k}\right)^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/603475/19341)

**EDIT2**

After I posted this, I received an [Announcer badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer?userid=19341) for one of the "Summing over..." questions. Does this mean that the links are somehow counted as to come from the outside?